# Creating user datasets when logged in

Tags: database, ee, users, custom-data

Did any of you encounter a situation where the solution is as follows:

- A logged in user able to do the following
- To create datasets on the fly. For e.g. 2019 - June - Shopping list - Fruits - [Apples.pdf, Bananas.doc, Oranges.txt, Pineapples.json, Raspberries.rtf]
- Apples, Bananas, etc can be any file type.
- They can store these datasets as a table in the database
- They are able to manage these datasets (Create-Read-Update-Delete)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but I can't see why you couldn't just use a Channel Entry with a grid field that has a field field column, and just setup front end forms for a user to edit channel entries (that they have authored). But you'll really have to ask your question more clearly for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're after, but you can use the plugin Shortlist to let visitors tag channel entries and then collect them into a list.

https://eeharbor.com/shortlist